# Firebase Performance Monitor breaks HTTP response

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-performance

I've integrated Firebase Performance and some of NSURLSession requests stoped working. I don't receive any callback from these requests. If I remove [FIRApp configure] or call [[FIRPerformance sharedInstance].instrumentationEnabled:NO] before it, than everything works well.
Have anyone met these issues?

Comment: Can you post your podfile and/or file a support ticket at https://firebase.google.com/support/ ?

Comment: I've already done it:
[2-5243000021691] Firebase Performance Monitor breaks HTTP response

Comment: This sounds like a bug that was fixed in the beginning of the year. Can you do a "pod update" to make sure you're using the latest versions? Right now Firebase iOS is on 4.11.0

Comment: Update to 4.11.0 solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear! For others who think they may be running into this bug, it involved redirect (3xx status code) responses from network requests.